# how to write this sql query - replacing each word of a string with matching value from another table

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
column1 column2
1       TARA JENK ERIK MURP
2       MATH SIER SHCK ELCP SBAR
3       CELN KRAB
```

Table 2:

```
ID    NAME
345   TARA
084   JENK
875   ERIK
345   MURP
```

Now, I want to query the data to be called within Java, so as I get the table 1 with column2's each word replaced by the ID matching in Table 2.

Is the SQL for this doable.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

EDITED:
Expected output:

```
column1  column2
1        345 084 875 435
2        980 245 352 355 425
3        523 233
```

Comment: PLease show the expected output.  Not clear from your question.

Comment: It is possible in SQL, but quite complicated.  Have you considered using a relational data structure for the first table?  That would be one row per entity/word.  Storing lists in strings is a bad idea.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: have added the expected output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes we did, not applicable in this particular implementation and also not in my control

Comment: a function will do the trick

Comment: I don't see any way to do it w/o incorporating some PL/SQL function.  If that is acceptable, there are probably several options.  Take a look at [Pipelined Functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php)

Comment: @Charlesliam: I can't run a function inside a Java code (added this info to the question too). Can have only SQL query.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: SQL query is the only option. Calling this from within Java code.

Comment: Then you will need to read in the two tables into java memory and do your own mapping.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Yes, I can do that; but can't I do this through SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that does what you want:

```
with words(id, word, rest, lev) as (
      select column1 as id,
             substr(column2, 1, instr(column2, ' ') - 1) as word,
             substr(column2, instr(column2, ' ') + 1) as rest,
             1 as lev
      from table1
      union all
      select id,
             (case when rest like '% %'
                   then substr(rest, 1, instr(rest, ' ') - 1)
                   else rest
              end) as word,
             (case when rest like '% %'
                   then substr(rest, instr(rest, ' ') + 1)
              end) as rest,
             lev + 1
      from words
      where rest is not null
     )
select w.id,
       listagg(coalesce(cast(t2.id as varchar2(255)), w.word), ' ') within group (order by w.lev)
from words w left outer join
     table2 t2
     on w.word = t2.name 
group by w.id;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/23807) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating it working.

Comment: Have checked your query in SQL developer, it's not working as required.

Comment: It works on SQL Fiddle.  Here is another example . . . http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/23812.

Comment: Can't access SQL Fiddle from the work network, will check later. But have double-checked it on sql developer and its not working there. Its quite complex though, let me see if I can work on your suggestion to recreate the tables as relational. (normalizing it)

Comment: Your version of Oracle may not support recursive CTEs or `listagg()` for string aggregation.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work as required by my question. But I have switched to recreating the tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With data as

```
create table table1(column1 number(9), column2 varchar2(100)); 

insert into table1
select  1, 'TARA JENK ERIK MURP' from dual union all
select  2, 'MATH SIER SHCK ELCP SBAR' from dual union all
select  3, 'CELN KRAB' from dual;

create table table2(IDS NUMBER(9), NAMES VARCHAR2(100));

insert into table2
select 345, 'TARA' from dual union all
select 084, 'JENK' from dual union all
select 875, 'ERIK' from dual union all
select 345, 'MURP' from dual union all
select 456, 'MATH' from dual union all
select 678, 'SIER' from dual union all
select 890, 'SHCK' from dual union all
select 123, 'ELCP' from dual union all
select 444, 'SBAR' from dual union all
select 666, 'CELN' from dual union all
select 888, 'KRAB' from dual;
```

Using Query

```
with tab1 as (select column1, 
                     regexp_substr(column2, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, level) element,
                     level seq
                from table1
               connect by regexp_substr(column2, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, level) is not null
                 and prior column2 = column2
                 and prior sys_guid() is not null)
select column1,
       listagg(ids, ' ') within group (order by seq) id,
       listagg(names, ' ') within group (order by seq) names
  from table2 join tab1 on (names = element)
 group by column1;
```

Output:

```
| COLUMN1 |                  ID |                    NAMES |
|---------|---------------------|--------------------------|
|       1 |      345 84 875 345 |      TARA JENK ERIK MURP |
|       2 | 456 678 890 123 444 | MATH SIER SHCK ELCP SBAR |
|       3 |             666 888 |                CELN KRAB |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my function version.

```
create or replace function txt_to_id(p_id number)
return varchar2 as
--SET serveroutput ON
--DECLARE
v_string VARCHAR2(100);
v_loc    NUMBER := 0;
v_slice  VARCHAR2(100);
v_id     NUMBER;
v_output VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT column2 INTO v_string FROM table1 WHERE column1 = p_id;
  --dbms_output.put_line('length v_string: '||LENGTH(v_string));
  --dbms_output.put_line('v_loc: '||v_loc);
  WHILE v_loc < LENGTH(v_string)
  LOOP
    --slice the string by find the space between
    v_slice := trim(SUBSTR(v_string, v_loc, instr(v_string,' ')));
  BEGIN
     SELECT id INTO v_id FROM table2 WHERE upper(name) LIKE upper(v_slice);
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     --dbms_output.put_line('Error Code: '|| SQLCODE||'-'||SQLERRM);
     v_output := v_output||' '||0;

  END;
  v_output := v_output||' '||v_id;
  --dbms_output.put_line('v_loc:'||v_loc);
  --dbms_output.put_line('v_slice:'||trim(v_slice));
  v_loc := v_loc+LENGTH(v_slice)+1;
END LOOP;
--dbms_output.put_line('v_output: '|| v_output);
return v_output;
END;
```

Usage:

```
select column2, txt_to_id(column1) from table1;
```

Result:

```
column2                      txt_to_id(column1)
TARA JENK ERIK MURP          345 84 875 346
MATH SIER SHCK ELCP SBAR     0  0  0  0  0 
CELN KRAB                    0  0
```

Comment: Pretty Good attempt always! :)

Comment: Thanks, but again not looking for a function. Just SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Version for Oracle 10:

```
select 
 column1, replace(s,chr(0)) column2
from (
 select 
 column1, (select count(0) from table2) n,
 regexp_replace(column2,'(\S+)',chr(0)||'\1'||chr(0)) s
 from table1
)
model reference a on (
 select rownum n, chr(0)||name||chr(0) name, id
 from table2
) dimension by (n) measures (name, id)
partition by (column1) dimension by (0 x) measures (s,n)
rules iterate(999) until (n[0]=0) 
(s[0]=replace(s[0],name[n[0]],id[n[0]]), n[0]=n[0]-1)
order by column1
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c232c/1)